# Debian bootloader is overlapping USB UEFI image

Tags: grub, debian-installer

I've recently decided to swap Windows for Debian on my notebook, so i began installing a non-free drivers-ready ISO from a bootable USB. When i went to check back on the installation, the screen was locked, and unlocking it greeted me with a login screen. However, my user and password don't work, and trying to restart the system outputs some errors on the command line, so i suspect that the notebook somehow went asleep during the installation and corrupted it.
I thought to myself "that's fine, i'll just liveboot Mint, wipe the disk and try again", however, it seems that Debian's GRUB overlaps the USB, making it so when i set the USB stick as the default boot option in the computer's BIOS, the bootloader goes through anyways, giving me only the option of booting the broken Debian installation. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Overlapping the USB" is not really a thing. It might that there are two boot options for the USB stick: one for UEFI mode and another for legacy mode. If your laptop is currently configured to "UEFI boot preferred" or "UEFI boot only", it might prefer the UEFI Debian over legacy boot from USB. Some laptop BIOSes don't have an explicit option to adjust the UEFI/legacy preference, which can make things awkward. "Secure boot enabled" usually means "UEFI boot only".

Comment: I see. The BIOS is really rudimentary and gives me little to no options, overall.
I'll try messing with GRUB's command line to see if i can boot directly from USB. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I suggest to learn how to invoke the BIOS' boot menu (selection of boot device).